# Configuring GeoServer layer for WMS-T and loop data in client display?

Tags: geoserver, animation, wms-time

I'm using GeoServer 2.10.1 to create an ImageMosaic layer from geotiffs of GOES east satellite imagery from NOAAPORT for the purpose of providing loops on the client side. My client side is currently using leaflet, and I've unsuccessfully tested my layer with the Leaflet.TimeDimension plugin, WMS animator, and Qgis with time manager plugin.

It was a struggle, but I seem to have successfully created the ImageMosaic layer with postGIS index storage.  The layer is currently configured to present time as a list, default value "use the domain value nearest to the reference value", reference value "CURRENT".  I have tried many configuration configurations for the time dimension.  I can't seem to request images over a given time domain.  I can manually request a specific image time.

When I try it in the leaflet plugin, I either get no image with a time in the loop control or "time not available".  The animator doesn't give anything but a blank image, though I'm not sure I'm using the aparam and avalues correctly.  Qgis gives me errors about time formatting when using various accuracy/resolution (no 'Z') and "could not find a suitable time format for value" when adding 'Z'.

The layer's info from GetCapabilities:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
  <Name>local:econus-vis</Name>
  <Title>NOAAPORT EastCONUS VIS in EPSG:3857</Title>
  <Abstract/>
  <KeywordList></KeywordList>
  <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
  <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
  <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <westBoundLongitude>-122.97668636167079</westBoundLongitude>
    <eastBoundLongitude>-49.48743670443121</eastBoundLongitude>
    <southBoundLatitude>14.287148240841406</southBoundLatitude>
    <northBoundLatitude>61.3126546641372</northBoundLatitude>
  </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
  <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-122.97668636167079" miny="14.287148240841406" maxx="-49.48743670443121" maxy="61.3126546641372"/>
  <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857" minx="-1.36897021052253E7" miny="1607181.05254824" maxx="-5508916.25460164" maxy="8697969.41913261"/>
  <Dimension name="time" default="current" units="ISO8601">2017-02-02T13:45:19.000Z,2017-02-02T14:00:18.000Z,2017-02-02T14:45:19.000Z,2017-02-02T15:00:18.000Z,2017-02-02T15:15:20.000Z,2017-02-02T15:30:19.000Z</Dimension>
  <Style>...</Style>
</Layer>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your capabilities document to the question